# Controller not being reconized after generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and I have geneted a page using the scafolding but I am having an issue.

I am getting the following error. I have placed the following in my routes.rb file in the config directory. And there is a controller called  routeplanner_controller.rb in the controller directory.

I am sorry if this is a generic problem I lit just installed ruby today for the first time.

No route matches [GET] "/routeplanner"

Rails.application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'routeplanner#index'

> No route matches [GET] "/routeplanner"

Rails.root: /home/david/sites/theflow

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

[image]

Comment: Try "routeplanners", plural.  You can check which routes you have setup by typing "rails routes" on the command line within your projects folders and you can modify these routes in your config/routes.rb file.

Comment: I'd recommend you read the guide on routing https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Root route corresponds to localhost:3000, not localhost:3000/routeplanner

Answer (score 1):

First we should have controller name in plural.
Write something like this in your routes "resources :routeplanners" or "resource :routeplanner"